# Bluetooth firmware not loading for Intel 7260

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, intel, firmware

I recently installed a Intel 7260 wireless module in the pcie slot of my ASUS N550jv CN270H laptop. The idea was to get bluetooth and wifi working flawlessly, as the originally installed atheros card has bad wifi management, and only randomly loads bluetooth correctly (there is a launchpad issue on this which has been open for several years now).

Nevertheless, now I have great wifi but no bluetooth at all.

I noticed this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1209124

The reporter shows a dmesg output, indicating that firmware is loaded:

```
[ 1.738944] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
```

However, my system doesn't report this in dmesg:

```
...
[    5.710455] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    5.710457] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.710463] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.710466] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.710479] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.719906] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.719916] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.719921] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    5.723154] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.723157] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.723163] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
...
```

I do, however, have the firmware installed, or at least something that looks like firmware:

```
herbert@machine ~ $ ls /lib/firmware/intel/
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
```

The firmware for the wifi seems to be loaded, which is consistent with the fact that my wifi works:

```
[    5.483705] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

So my kernel seems to do something w.r.t. bluetooth, but not load firmware. Also, `hcitool dev` shows no devices and /sys/class/bluetooth/ is empty. Also `lshw` shows no bluetooth devices, but it does show the wifi card:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan1
   version: 73
   serial: d8:fc:93:dd:96:9f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-33-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:55 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
```

Kernel info:

```
Linux machine 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Obviously, I want a fix, but answers to these might also help (and I will be grateful!):

- How can I find out what firmware I should use for my kernel/device combo? I found this page which informs on this for the wifi, but none for the bluetooth: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0.tgz
- I'm assuming the Bluetooth device and the wifi device need different firmware, even though then are the same physical piece of electronics, is that correct?
- Can I try to manually inject firmware, as modprobe/rmmod/lsmod/insmod do for modules, and see what error I get?
- What kernel version should I use? I upgraded from 3.13.something-something to 3.16.0-33 using `apt-get install` in the hopes of having better 'firmware support'. This did not help.

Comment: Ouch, the problem was trivial. Bluetooth was disabled in the BIOS. In my defense, it was well hidden behind a "USB Features" menu.